# How to print hexademical from byte[]?

Tags: java, websocket

My goal is to follow the RFC6455 [Page 8]

```
The server would then take the SHA-1 hash of this,
   giving the value 0xb3 0x7a 0x4f 0x2c 0xc0 0x62 0x4f 0x16 0x90 0xf6
   0x46 0x06 0xcf 0x38 0x59 0x45 0xb2 0xbe 0xc4 0xea.
```

I am assuming `0xb3` equals to 179.

This is the lines of code I use to print the byte[]. The LOGGER is sl4fj.

```
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketWorkerThread.class);

    public void onOpen() {
        String GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
        byte[] SHA_1_hash_value = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(
                ("dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==" + GUID).getBytes()
        );
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : SHA_1_hash_value) {
          sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        }
    }
```

My expected result:

```
0xb3 0x7a 0x4f 0x2c 0xc0 0x62 0x4f 0x16 0x90 0xf6
   0x46 0x06 0xcf 0x38 0x59 0x45 0xb2 0xbe 0xc4 0xea
```

The actual result:

```
64 3A 23 A1 A9 CE 6D 23 B2 71 B8 D5 45 CE A8 5F 25 CD 45 1E
```

Comment: Is `GUID` a string? Do you need to hash its string representation or its actual byte value? Do you really need to hash the base-64 string and not its decoded form?

Comment: @knittl it's a string from the RFC. Sorry, I just added it. Please take a look. I need to hash the concated string (I am following the RFC). Now, I just need to confirm whether the code is correct. The RFC said the hash will give value `0xb3 ...`. However I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @kidfrom: [RFC4655](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4655)? I cannot find "b3", "hash of this", nor the word "GUID" in its text

Comment: @Slaw the values are different. "0xb3 0x7a" and "64 3a" (I'm assuming those values to be the real values, not examples)

Comment: @knittl I am very sorry. It's RFC6455. Anyway, I have found the error. The actual result is `B3 7A ...`. It matched with the RFC now.

Comment: one more comment: I would be surprised if you really need to send the stirng representation of the hash. It is quite inefficient. Are you sure that this is not just for visualizing the value inside the RFC? In other words, you would base64 encode the hash value (`0xb37a…`) and _not_ the string encoding (`"0xb3 0x7a …"`)

Comment: @knittl It's just for visualizing. I would base64 encoded the hash value.

Comment: Your code is essentially correct. You just need `sb.append(String.format("0x%02x ", b));` for exactly what you posted you expect. WIth that, I get `0xb3 0x7a 0x4f 0x2c 0xc0 0x62 0x4f 0x16 0x90 0xf6 0x46 0x06 0xcf 0x38 0x59 0x45 0xb2 0xbe 0xc4 0xea`

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketWorkerThread.class);

public void onOpen() {
    String GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    byte[] SHA_1_hash_value = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(
            ("dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==" + GUID).getBytes()
    );
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : SHA_1_hash_value) {
      sb.append("0x" + String.format("%02X ", b).toLowerCase());
    }
}
```